# Java workspace and file path

Tags: java, file, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a probably easy to solve problem.
I am having a folder in my project and want to get it using the relative path:

```
new File("/folder")
```

this gives me `FileNotFoundException`

if I try  like this

```
new File("d:/workspace/project/folder")
```

it works

I suspect that it does not work because of this:
`new File("").getAbsolutePath()` returns : `D:\eclipse`
So not the path of the workspace.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to change some settings in eclipse

Comment: You might want your program to take as input the workspace location.  In Eclipse you can set up a run target for the java program and use the Eclipse pre-defined variable ${workspace_loc} to pass the location of your workspace in.  Eclipse main menu -> Run -> Run Configurations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found my answer in Run Cofigurations like djna suggested, but not in the Environment Tab but in the Arguments Tab. There is a working directory section in which d:\eclipse was set and which needed to be set to ${workspace_loc:myproject}

Answer (score 4):

Don has pointed that you use a absolute path. That is the problem.

By default the working directory in Eclipse is the path of the project where is the program that you execute.

You can always know the working directory by displaying this property :

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new File("/folder")
```

is not a relative path, it is an absolute one.
If you want to access the relative Path use

```
new File("folder")
```

or

```
new File("./folder")
```

Comment: The new File("folder") gives me D:\eclipse\folder and the new File("./folder") gives me D:\eclipse\.\folder

Comment: That's why your D:\eclipse seems to be your working folder. Try to setup eclipse like djna told you to. But new File("/folder") should result in C:\folder

Answer (score 1):

Can u try this?

```
File file = new File("folder");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the run configurations you can specify the working directory for the launch. This might vary in different Eclipses but for me:

```
Run->Run Cofigurations ...
Select Java Application, right Click New
Environment Tab gives you a chance to specify the working directory
    Select Other, and then Workspace ... to specify a project in your workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

`D:\eclipse` is the root folder of your project. If you create another project in `D:\java` in the same workspace, `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` will return `D:\java` so this is independent of the path of your workspace.

If you want a folder inside your project, use `.`, example:

```
System.out.println(new File(".\\test").getAbsolutePath());
```