# How does file.getAbsolutePath work?

Tags: java

This is the code:

```
String filename = "sql.txt";
File file = new File(filename);
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(path);
```

My text file resides in E drive but when I print out the path it is in C drive. Why does this happen?

Comment: Sure about your E drive? Looks like you create a new File in your java application's working directory.

Comment: You create a file in the working directory of java - because you didnt give java an explicit storage place. If you want to get your sql.txt in your e: drive than you have to specify the path like: `String filename = "e:\sql.txt";`

Comment: Your path is incomplete, hence it is creating a file in your working directory!

Comment: @Jörn Buitink Yes i'm sure it is in E drive. I went into the C directory and checked but I couldn't see any file in C. Does it create some temp file during run time?

Comment: `File` is not a real file, it's an abstraction only over a probably existing real file system file. In your example, no code says for your drive E, it only says "sql.txt within the current working directory" and, I suspect, it is on your C drive thus your absolute path refers to your local directory you start JVM from, isn't it? Just to be sure, print out `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: @ Lyubomyr Shaydariv - new File(".").getAbsolutePath() gives me the path of my workspace. Is that what is meant by "current working directory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided a path which is neither absolute nor canonical.

```
String filename = "sql.txt";
```

Hence, the pathname is returned as simply the current user directory.

Have a look at the documentation for the [getAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) method in the [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class:

> If this abstract pathname is already absolute, then the pathname
>   string is simply returned as if by the getPath() method. If this
>   abstract pathname is the empty abstract pathname then the pathname
>   string of the current user directory, which is named by the system
>   property user.dir, is returned. Otherwise this pathname is resolved in
>   a system-dependent way. On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made
>   absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On
>   Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by
>   resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the
>   pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user
>   directory.

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps

- Go to run configuration
- Click argument tab
- Change the working directory to ${workspace_loc:myproject}

Reference 
[Java workspace and file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152857/java-workspace-and-file-path)